# Date.Format is outputting very strange dates

Tags: go

I have a Date.Time var that is:

```
2022-03-28 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

when i do:

```
Date.Time.Format("2003-12-22")
```

I get something like this:

```
1999-131-311
```

Looking to just have it be formatted to YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Always look at [the predefined layouts](https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants) first. Only if what you need isn't there, copy one that is close and modify it without changing any of the numbers. Here, use `.Format(time.DateOnly)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST", "2006-01-02" are layout to convert your date.

**Code:**

```
originalDate, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST", "2022-03-28 00:00:00 +0000 UTC")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

formattedDate := originalDate.Format("2006-01-02")
fmt.Println(formattedDate)
```

**Output:**

```
2022-03-28
```